# `anchor build` fails because of package `regex`

Tags: anchor

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.soldev.app/course/intro-to-anchor, but when I tried to run `anchor build` I got:

```
BPF SDK: /Users/anhdungle/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.4/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `regex = "=1.10.3"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.8.4, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `anchor-attribute-access-control v0.28.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-attribute-access-control = "=0.28.0"` of package `anchor-lang v0.28.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-lang = "=0.28.0"` of package `anchor-counter v0.1.0
```

although I have already installed `regex@1.10.3` by `cargo update regex@1.10.3`

Comment: Hey there did you installed anchor through AVM?
Also what is ur avm v? Rust v ? Solana cli v and your cargo dependencies.

Comment: Hi, yes, I installed anchor through avm.
`avm 0.29.0`, `rustc 1.76.0 (07dca489a 2024-02-04)`, `rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)`, `solana-cli 1.9.4 (src:8ce65878; feat:3258470607)`
```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.28.0"
```

Comment: Ok your solana cli is definitely outdated.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it and it works now